# How to remove a tag when the contenteditable div contains text?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How would you completely remove the tags when the user enters something into the contenteditable `<p>`?

**HTML: Before**

```
<p contenteditable="true"></p>
```

Now if the user types `*Some text*` into the contenteditable `<p>`, the page will now display:

**HTML: After**

```
Some text
```

Rather than

```
<p contenteditable="true">Some text</p>
```

Comment: Why do you want to remove the paragraph tags?

Comment: You want to use .text() on the paragraph tag and replace the tag with the text. If that's what you want to do. Can't give you an example at the minute I'm on my phone.

Comment: @evolutionxbox the user enters an image URL into the contenteditable `<p>` and the image is then displayed onto the page. The problem is that the image that is on the page is still wrapped around the `<p>` tag so all styles applied to the `<p>` tag - especially the `position: absolute` also apply to the image. By removing the p tags, its styles don't apply to the image

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to remove the `p` tag on pressing `Enter` key, you can use the following:

```js
$('p').keyup(function(e) {
  if ($(this).attr('contentEditable') == "true") {
    if (e.which == '13') {
      $(this).contents().unwrap('p');
    }
  }
});
```

```css
p {
  border: 2px solid gray;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p contenteditable="true">Edit me and press Enter</p>
```

Comment: Works great but is there a way to do this without pressing enter? So as soon as there is text in the tag

Comment: Just remove `if` condition block, it will work. But that will work as soon as single character is added or text is pasted.

Answer (score 0):

Use [**replaceWith()**](http://api.jquery.com/replacewith/)

```js
var text = $('[contenteditable="true"]').text();
$('[contenteditable="true"]').replaceWith(text);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p contenteditable="true">Some text</p>
```

Comment: Unless the OP asked for jQuery don't assume they want it. Please, supply a vanilla JS solution as well.

Comment: @evolutionxbox, the OP has jquery tagged in his question

Comment: Ah. My observation skills at top notch again I see.

Comment: Considering OP wants to replace the paragraph with an image with the p content (a url), I'm not sure `.replaceWith()` is appropriate.